# Content security policy Subdomain of subdomain

Tags: content-security-policy

I am trying to make a CSP for my system. I know that for the domay I need 'self'. For my subdomains I need *.mywebsite.com (if I use the wildcard function). But what if I have a subdomain of my subdomain? something like test1.test2.mywebsite.com. Will the wildcard still work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will match. From [CSP3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/)

> Hosts such as example.com (which matches any resource on the host,
> regardless of scheme) or *.example.com (which matches any resource on
> the host’s subdomains (and any of its subdomains' subdomains, and so
> on))

Comment: Thank you! Checked out the link and found the answer on my question.